# Sonatype Nexus 3 HTTPS step by step?

Tags: https, nexus

please help configure Nexus with using Https proxy? Can't understand how i can seting my nginx or apache for Nexus for working from 80 to 443 port? Now our Nexus server work on 80 port and haven't and apache or nginx. I seen many man's about this, but can't totally understand...

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/system-configuration/configuring-ssl#ConfiguringSSL-UsingAReverseProxyServer

Maybe anybody can a little step by step tell my how i can simple configure https with Nexus?

So thx!!! 8-)

Comment: *Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of the ansible role from which I extracted the folowing link.* If this can help, here is a simple template file used in a nexus3 ansible role to configure apache as a reverse proxy to nexus: https://github.com/ansible-ThoTeam/nexus3-oss/blob/master/templates/nexus-vhost.conf